# How to install IOTA in a small device supports LoraWAN?

Tags: tangle, iota-network, internet-of-things

I found an article here :([Link to the article](https://medium.com/@harmvandenbrink/lorawan-and-iota-proof-of-concept-of-storing-data-in-real-time-in-the-tangle-9ba6a109b552)) entitled "**LoraWAN and IOTA: Proof of Concept of storing data in real time in the Tangle**".

The thing is not clear to me is that if `IOTA` has been **installed** on a small device supports `LoraWAN` (https://lora-alliance.org/about-lorawan) in this proof of concept? (You can see an example of this small device here: [Link to the device](https://medium.com/@harmvandenbrink/lorawan-and-iota-proof-of-concept-of-storing-data-in-real-time-in-the-tangle-9ba6a109b552).)

And if so, which version of `IOTA` (**which language?**) this version? : https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js ?

And if so, does it mean that it is possible to install a `JavaScript` version of `IOTA` on a small device supports `LoraWAN`? Because usually we need to run a `C/C++` code on a device such as small devices support `LoraWAN` and apparently there is no version of `IOTA` implemented in `C` language in its official `Github` repository (https://github.com/iotaledger).

Or maybe in this proof of concept, `IOTA` has been installed in **another more powerful device** (**which device? it is not clear to me**.)

Am I right? What is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: It might be best to ask directly the author of the article. I don't think it gives sufficient information for anyone to be able to repeat or fully understand the setup.

Comment: My general question is that if it is possible to install IOTA on a LoraWAN device? or as @ben75 says, the IOTA is installed on an ordinary computer? And in this case, what is the role of LoraWAN device? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoraWAN is a protocol for data-transfer (not a device). It's a very *low level* protocol, specially designed for low power devices.

AFAIK, LoraWAN is designed in such a way that a small device can send messages to a nearby LoraWAN-Gateway through radio signal. The gateway have an antenna to receive messages and a high bandwidth internet connection (wifi, cellular, ...) to forward messages to the internet.

In the linked article, the strategy was to **implement the iota part on a normal computer** simply listening for messages on LoraWAN network and encapsulate them in an iota transaction. The author was connected to "[TheThingsNetwork](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/)" : an open network of LoraWAN-Gateway.

Comment: Thank you. But it the article, it's mentioned they use a programmable LoraWAN based device link. So, if we've to install IOTA on a normal computer, what is role of this **small device**? Does it mean we've to connect this small device to a normal computer? (Otherwise, this small device is not able to run IOTA and send transaction to IOTA tangle?) How can we imagine a general view of this architecture? Thank you again

Comment: I think the proposed idea in the article has an architecture like this figure: https://imgur.com/a/ZvkgkBu Am I wrong? Thanks